# A gcc compilation error (concerning copy c'tors) which seems odd (at least to me)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

So, I have the following code which fails to compile on gcc 4.2.1 on OSX. The error I get is:

```
testref.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testref.cpp:10: error: ‘A::A(const A&)’ is private
testref.cpp:20: error: within this context
```

And here's the code

```
#include <cstdio>

class A {
public:
    A() { i=0; printf("A ctor\n"); }
    ~A() { printf("A dtor\n"); }

private:
    A(const A& other) { i=other.i; printf("A COPY CTOR\n"); }
    A& operator=(const A& other) { i=other.i; printf("A COPY operator\n"); return *this; }
private:
    int i;
};

void f(const A &aref) {
    printf("dummy\n");
} 

int main() {
    f(A());
    return 0; 
}
```

This copy constructor is not needed in this case, as f gets a reference (I made it public to see if it gets called and it doesn't). 
Additionally, I've made f get the object by value, and still neither copy constructor nor operator= gets called. I suspect this may have something to do with optimizations.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Compiles successfully on gcc 4.6.2 on Arch linux.

Comment: compiles ok on MSVS2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen into a subtle standards issue. GCC is right, but the error is pretty bad: Compiling the same with `clang` gives:

```
test.cpp:20:7: warning: C++98 requires an accessible copy constructor for class
              'A' when binding a reference to a temporary; was private
```

Edit: I don't have my standards copy nearby to give you the full reasoning. Hopefully someone else (or Google) can.

Comment: Can you post a quote from the standard to back this up? Note that it's a const reference, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The example in 12.2.2 seems to be what you're looking for re: this, at least in the draft; http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Examples are just there to make normative text more clear, so there must be some normative text explaining it. It might also be more useful to use n3242 or n3290 to quote from.

Comment: I personally believe this is a bug in both compilers (I think gcc 4.6 fixes this). As I interpret the standard, the copy ctor is required for cases when a temporary is created by something like a function return, even when RVO takes place; the compilers seem to be overly careful here. I could never find any reason in the standard why `const T& t = T();` should require an accessible copy ctor.